# Tomcat 9 could not find ServletContextListener with @WebListener annotation after proguard

Tags: tomcat, servlets, proguard, tomcat9, servlet-listeners

Tomcat 9 could not find ServletContextListener with @WebListener annotation after proguard.

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {


}
```

It works before proguard.

After proguard, the class name is changed to "a".

```
@WebListener
public class a implements ServletContextListener {


}
```

From java decompiler, the @WebListener annotation is kept in the obfuscated class. Tomcat 9 did not call the listener and no error messages.

After adding the listener in web.xml, did not help.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.a</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

the listener was ignored and no error messages.